# Solving 4X4 sudoku in maple

Tags: recursion, sudoku, backtracking, maple

So I am trying to use recursion and backtracking to solve a 4x4 sudoku. 
When I call SolveSmallSudoku(L);
                        "Solving now..."
it gives me this "Error, (in SolveSmallSudoku) Matrix index out of range"
But I cannot spot any bug that is related to my matrix, L, indices. It seems like that my program doesn't do my backtracking part properly. I think my findPossibleEntries procedure works fine. It does find all the possible values for that certain cell. Anyone got any hint?

```
> L := Matrix(4,4,[ [0,4,0,0],[2,0,0,3],[4,0,0,1],[0,0,3,0] ]);
 > isFull := proc(L)
    local x, y;    
        for x from 1 to 4 do
        for y from 1 to 4 do
         if L[x,y]=0 then
                 return false;
              end if;
           end do;
        end do;

        return true;
        end proc;

>findPossibleEntries := proc(L, i, j)
    local x, y, possible:=[0,0,0,0];
    local r:=1, c:=1;


#Checking possible entries in ith row
for y from 1 to 4 do
    if not L[i,y] = 0 then
       possible[L[i,y]] := 1;     
    end if;
end do;

#Checking possible entries in jth col
for x from 1 to 4 do
    if not L[x,j] = 0 then
       possible[L[x,j]] := 1;

    end if;
end do;

#Checking possible entries block by block
if i >= 1 and i <= 2 then
   r := 1;
elif i >= 3 and i <= 4 then
   r := 3;
end if;

if j >= 1 and j <= 2 then
   c := 1;
elif j >= 3 and j <= 4 then
   c := 3;
end if;

#Using for-loop to find possible entries in the block
for x in range(r, r+1) do
      for y in range(c, c+1) do

            if not L[x,y] = 0 then
               possible[L[x,y]] := 1;
            end if;
      end do;
end do;


#Now the list, possible, only holds the possible entries
for x from 1 to 4 do
    if possible[x] = 0 then
       possible[x] := x;
    else
       possible[x] := 0;
    end if;
end do;

return possible;

end proc;

>SolveSmallSudoku := proc(L)
local x, y, i:=0, j:=0, possibleVal:=[0,0,0,0];

if isFull(L) then
   print("Solved!");
   print(L);
   return;
else
   print("Solving now...");

   for x from 1 to 4 do
       for y from 1 to 4 do
          if L[x,y] = 0 then
               i:=x;
               j:=y;
               break;
          end if
       end do;
       #Breaks the outer loop as well
       if L[x,y] = 0 then
          break;
       end if

   end do;    

#Finds all the possibilities for i,j
possibleVal := findPossibleEntries(L,i,j);

#Traverses the list, possibleVal to find the correct entries and finishes the sudoku recursively 
for x from 1 to 4 do
    if not possibleVal[x] = 0 then
       L[i,j]:= possibleVal[x];
       SolveSmallSudoku(L);
    end if;
end do;
#Backtracking
 L[i,j]:= 0;

end if;


end proc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of,

```
#Breaks the outer loop as well
   if L[x,y] = 0 then
      break;
   end if
```

As you had it originally that outer check was trying to access L[1,5] for your given example L.

Instead, replace the `break` in the inner loop with,

```
x:=4; break;
```

That will cause the outer loop to also complete at the next iteration (which happens to occur right after the inner loop ends or breaks. So you'll get the full break you wanted.

The code then seems to work as you intended, and the solution gets printed for your input example.

Comment: You can see it yourself by running in debugger, or by `print(x,y)` right before outer `if L[x,y]=0 then` that I suggested you remove. Note the following usual behaviour, which results in 5 as final value for `y` when concluding this loop: `for y from 1 to 4 do; end do: y;`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Do you know the idea behind this "usual behaviour", where the condition in the for-loop is `y <= 4` instead of `y < 4`? 

(Note that I'm not the OP, why I havn't done any serious debugging on the code posted.)